# webpart interview question, whats wrong with it or better way of doing this

Tags: web-part

this is like an interview question given to me by someone, can you tell me whats wrong with it or if there is a better way of doing this. this will be run in a large enterprise. NOTE : Demo.Tasks.Task is a custom object whose deninition is not shown in this code.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using System.Collections;

namespace Demo.WebParts
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description for MyTasks.
    /// </summary>
    [DefaultProperty("Text"),
        ToolboxData("<{0}:WebPart1 runat=server></{0}:WebPart1>"),
        XmlRoot(Namespace="Demo.Tasks")]
    public class MyTasks : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
    {
        private const string defaultListName = "";
        private string listName = defaultListName;
        private ArrayList alTasks;

        [Browsable(true),
            Category("Miscellaneous"),
            DefaultValue(defaultListName),
            WebPartStorage(Storage.None),
            FriendlyName("List Name Filter"),
            Description("The name of sps lists to gather tasks from")]
        public string ListName
        {
            get
            {
                return listName;
            }

            set
            {
                listName = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            alTasks = new ArrayList();
            try
            {
                SPWeb myWeb = SPControl.GetContextWeb(this.Context);
                foreach(SPList list in myWeb.Lists)
                {
                    if(list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Tasks)
                    {
                        if(list.Title == listName)
                        {
                            getTasksFromList(list);
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach(SPWeb subWeb in myWeb.Webs)
                    foreach(SPList list in subWeb.Lists)
                        if(list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.Tasks)
                            getTasksFromList(list);
            }
            catch
            {}
        }

        private void getTasksFromList(SPList list)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<list.ItemCount;i++)
            {
                if(list.Items[i]["AssignedTo"].ToString() == this.Context.User.Identity.Name)
                {
                    Demo.Tasks.Task tsk = Tasks.Task.CreateTask();
                    tsk.Title = list.Items[i]["Title"].ToString();
                    tsk.DueDate = (DateTime)list.Items[i]["DueDate"];
                    tsk.Description = list.Items[i]["Description"].ToString();
                    tsk.Priority = (int)list.Items[i]["Priority"];
                    alTasks.Add(tsk);

                    //now update the item
                    list.Items[i]["LastViewed"] = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Render this Web Part to the output parameter specified.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="output"> The HTML writer to write out to </param>
        protected override void RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            try
            {
                string strHTML = "";
                for(int i=0;i<alTasks.Count;i++)
                {
                    Demo.Tasks.Task tsk = (Demo.Tasks.Task)alTasks[i];
                    strHTML = strHTML + "The task " + tsk.Title + " is due on " + tsk.DueDate + "<BR>" + tsk.Description + "<BR><BR>";
                }
                output.Write(strHTML);
            }
            catch
            {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the CrossListQueryInfo + CAML query to retrieve the tasks. It's fast as hell, much faster then then the code that you wrote. According to some measures by Waldek Mastykarz ([click click](http://mastykarz.nl/blog/images/Performanceofcontentaggregationquerieson_7504/ExFirstRun_3.png)), it appears that the CLQI is fast incredibly fast. Using the SPSiteDataQuery may be an option of 2nd choice. Especially in large environments, this will be a good idea to use.

Info on how to use the CrossListQueryInfo can be found [in my blogpost](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/bas/archive/2009/03/27/using-the-crosslistqueryinfo-and-crosslistquerycache.aspx). Make sure to read the post entirely and make sure to make use of it correctly: wrong usage of the CrossListQueryInfo can cause some loss of performance, although it will still be faster than your code.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know what is not good in this code, here are the first things I'm thinking of

```
foreach(SPWeb subWeb in myWeb.Webs)
       foreach(SPList list in subWeb.Lists)
```

-> SPWeb not disposed properly, consider using the Using statement or dispose it manually in a try/catch/finally block

```
list.Items[i]["LastViewed"] = DateTime.Now;
```

->will not take effect until you call Update() on the SPListItem

Empty try/catch statement hides an exception -> bad practice, better let it blows than doing nothing, you should rather handle and/or log the exception

```
 private void getTasksFromList(SPList list)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<list.ItemCount;i++)
            {
                if(list.Items[i]["AssignedTo"].ToString() == this.Context.User.Identity.Name)
                {
```

-> Wrong way to iterate through list.Items
you should rather do something like that:

```
 private void getTasksFromList(SPList list)
        {
            SPListItemCollection items = list.items;
            for(int i=0;i<items.Count;i++)
            {
                SPListItem listItem = items[i];
                if(listItem["AssignedTo"].ToString() == this.Context.User.Identity.Name)
                {
```

I may have missed some stuff still

Comment: `catch {}` ? :-)

Comment: It's there -> Empty try/catch statement hides an exception :D

Comment: ah sorry... :-)